# Creating a database on Redis

Tags: database, redis

I have two interrelated (sort of) txt files and planning to put them in Redis databases. Both files supposed to be loaded as Hashtables.
The question is about automated writing of records as two files combined are about 2 million lines.

I would also like to know how do I even store these databases and hand them over to Back-End team? (I am working on the other branch of team, interpreting algorithms).

My apologies for not very smart of a question, I started learning Redis like couple of days ago and yet know almost nothing about it.

Files have following structure:
File with graph nodes:

```
670287 {amount of records}
0 55.8905505 37.4838629
1 55.8923283 37.4833778
...
```

where field 0 is index, fileds 1 and 2 are latitude and longitude;
File with Edges:

```
728208 {amount of records}
257079 596946 26.82 70 1 0 street name
596946 596937 24.39 70 7 0 street name
...
```

where fields 0 and 1 are origin and destination nodes from first file, the rest are edge properties.
So I need to have two databeses of Hashtables:

One with following structure:

```
key 0 lat 55.8905505 lon 37.4838629
key 1 lat 55.8923283 lon 37.4833778
...
```

And the other:

```
key 0 origin 257079 destination 596946 way_length 26.82 velocity 70 traffic 1 bilateral 0 street "street name"
...
```